# re-indexing problem with suggesters from elastic v1.7 to elastic 7.X problem

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have problem with the reindex, I‘m not sure 100% that the solution I found is the best as we are having issues to work with the index from the java client. So I want to confirm if the re-indexing steps are correct:

Problem Description:
I have an index on an old v1.7 that need to migrate to elasticsearch v7.x that uses context suggesters.

```
GET /autocompleteterms_v20/_search?pretty 
{
 "took" : 2,
 "timed_out" : false,
 "_shards" : {
 "total" : 1,
 "successful" : 1,
 "failed" : 0
},
 "hits" : {
 "total" : 4130,
 "max_score" : 1.0,
 "hits" : [ {
 "_index" : "autocompleteterms_v20",
 "_type" : "autoitem",
 "_id" : "en_incorporated_by_reference",
 "_score" : 1.0,
 "_source":{ "name": "incorporated by reference", "name_suggest": { "input": "incorporated by reference", "context": { "lang": "en" }, "weight": 393 } }
 }, {
 "_index" : "autocompleteterms_v20",
 "_type" : "autoitem",
 "_id" : "en_double_gaming",
 "_score" : 1.0,
 "_source":{ "name": "double gaming", "name_suggest": { "input": "double gaming", "context": { 
 "lang": "en" }, "weight": 371 } }
 }, {
 "_index" : "autocompleteterms_v20",
"_type" : "autoitem",
"_id" : "en_checking_for_players",
"_score" : 1.0,
"_source":{ "name": "checking for players", "name_suggest": { "input": "checking for players", 
 "context": { "lang": "en" }, "weight": 2 } }
},
```

---

```
GET /autocompleteterms_v20/_mapping?pretty
{
"autocompleteterms_v20" : {
"mappings" : {
"autoitem" : {
"properties" : {
"name" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"name_suggest" : {
"type" : "completion",
"analyzer" : "standard",
"payloads" : true,
"preserve_separators" : false,
"preserve_position_increments" : false,
"max_input_length" : 50,
 "context" : {
 "lang" : {
 "type" : "category",
 "path" : "lang_field",
 "default" : [ "en" ]
  }
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
```

To reindex to the new cluster I have found that there were some breaking changes in v5 for the suggesters so when tried to transform the fields of the index on the reindex

1. First I create the mapping:

   ```
   PUT autocompleteterms_v20 {
    "settings": {
    "index": {
    "number_of_shards": 2,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
   },
   "mappings": {
    "properties": {
    "name": {
     "type": "text"
   },
    "name_suggest": {
   "type": "completion",
   "analyzer": "standard",
   "preserve_separators": false,
   "preserve_position_increments": false,
   "max_input_length": 50,
   "contexts": [
   {
    "name": "lang",
    "type": "category",
    "path": "lang_field"
     }
   ]
   }
   }
   }
   }
   {
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "shards_acknowledged" : true,
    "index" : "autocompleteterms_v20"
   }
   ```
2. After that I reindex changing the field context to contexts:

   ```
    POST _reindex {
    "source": {
    "remote": {
     "host": http://x.x.x.x:9200,
     "username": "user",
     "password": "password"
    },
    "index": "autocompleteterms_v20"
    },
    "dest": {
    "index": "autocompleteterms_v20"
   },
   "script": {
   "source": """ 
   ctx._source.name_suggest.contexts = ctx._source.name_suggest.context;
   ctx._source['name_suggest'].remove('context');
   """,
   "lang": "painless"
   }
   }
   {
   "took" : 366,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "total" : 4130,
   "updated" : 0,
   "created" : 4130,
   "deleted" : 0,
   "batches" : 5,
   "version_conflicts" : 0,
   "noops" : 0,
   "retries" : {
   "bulk" : 0,
   "search" : 0
   },
   "throttled_millis" : 0,
   "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
   "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
   "failures" : [ ]
   }
   ```
3. When I make a query using explicit context I get results:

   ```
    POST /autocompleteterms_v20/_search {
    "suggest": {
    "text": "spirit",
    "completion": {
    "field": "name_suggest",
    "contexts": {
    "lang": [ 
       { "context": "en" }
      ]
      }
     }
     }
     }
     }
     {
     "took" : 5,
     "timed_out" : false,
     "_shards" : {
     "total" : 2,
     "successful" : 2,
     "skipped" : 0,
     "failed" : 0
     },
     "hits" : {
     "total" : {
     "value" : 0,
     "relation" : "eq"
     },
     "max_score" : null,
     "hits" : [ ]
     },
     "suggest" : {
     "completeMe" : [
     {
     "text" : "spirit",
     "offset" : 0,
     "length" : 6,
     "options" : [
     {
      "text" : "spirit",
      "_index" : "autocompleteterms_v20",
      "_type" : "_doc",
      "_id" : "en_spirit",
      "_score" : 290.0,
      "_source" : {
      "name_suggest" : {
      "input" : "spirit",
      "weight" : 290,
      "contexts" : {
      "lang" : "en"
       }
      },
      "name" : "spirit"
      },
      "contexts" : {
      "lang" : [
      "en"
     ]
     }
     },
     {
    "text" : "spirit of the game",
    "_index" : "autocompleteterms_v20",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "en_spirit_of_the_game",
    "_score" : 34.0,
    "_source" : {
    "name_suggest" : {
     "input" : "spirit of the game",
    "weight" : 34,
    "contexts" : {
    "lang" : "en"
    }
   },
   "name" : "spirit of the game"
    },
   "contexts" : {
    "lang" : [
       "en"
      ]
      }
    }
   ```
4. But when I make a query without context I get an error:

   ```
    POST /autocompleteterms_v20/_search
    {
    "suggest": {
     "completeMe": {
     "text": "spirit",
     "completion": {
     "field": "name_suggest"
     }
    }
   }
   }
    {
     "error" : {
      "root_cause" : [
     {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Missing mandatory contexts in context query"
     }
     ],
     "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
    {
    "shard" : 0,
    "index" : "autocompleteterms_v20",
    "node" : "B7EpKWRVRzGkLCnl7CZapQ",
    "reason" : {
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Missing mandatory contexts in context query"
    }
    }
     ],
    "caused_by" : {
   "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
   "reason" : "Missing mandatory contexts in context query",
   "caused_by" : {
   "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
   "reason" : "Missing mandatory contexts in context query"
    }
    }
     },
     "status" : 400
   }
   ```

But in the breaking change from v5.0 we have https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_suggester.html#_completion_mapping_with_multiple_contexts

it is mentioned:
"New queries with no context against a context-enabled completion field yields results from all indexed suggestions"

**In this context I have two main questions:**

1. Is the reindexing of the old index is done correctly?
2. How can I do queries without choosing context against that index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you did everything correctly!
2. You can't as there was another [suggester change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_context_completion_suggester) in ES 7.0 that made the provision of context mandatory because otherwise the performance was too degraded

> Context Completion Suggester
>
> The ability to query and index context enabled suggestions without context, deprecated in 6.x, has been removed. **Context enabled suggestion queries without contexts have to visit every suggestion, which degrades the search performance considerably.**

Comment: Thanks alot for your prompt answer!